# Return largest group from groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Is there a simple way to return the group with the most rows by a call to `df.groupby(..)`?

```
# Return group most rows e.g.
largest_group = df.groupby("community_area").max()
```

Comment: What do you mean by largest group? Group with the most rows?

Comment: Yep the group with the most rows

Comment: `df[df['community_area'].isin(df['community_area'].value_counts().head(1).index)]` ?

Comment: you should realy post a [mcve] though ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

max with key function returning the shape

```
>>> df
   one  two
a  1.0  1.0
b  2.0  2.0
c  3.0  3.0
d  2.0  4.0
e  2.0  5.0
>>> gb = df.groupby('one')
>>> key,grp = max(gb,key=lambda x: x[1].shape)
>>> grp
   one  two
b  2.0  2.0
d  2.0  4.0
e  2.0  5.0
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Then it's just:

```
group_with_max_rows = df["community_area"].mode[0]

# all rows in that group:
df[df['community_area'] == group_with_max_rows]
```

Comment: This is great, wwii posted a solution slightly earlier though - thank you

Comment: @TomSelleck if this is a better solution go ahead and accept it.

Comment: @wwii I'm using yours, everyone's a winner

Answer (score 2):

Use `groupby`, `size`, and `idxmax`
The point of this is to leverage the `groupby` object and the things it calculates to reduce calculating more than we need to.

```
df.groupby('A').pipe(
    lambda g: df.loc[g.groups[g.size().idxmax()]]
)

    A
1   2
5   2
10  2
15  2
```

---

Less `pipe` and more readable

```
g = df.groupby('A')
k = g.size().idxmax()
i = g.groups[k]

df.loc[i]
```

---

#### Setup

```
np.random.seed([3, 141592])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(10, size=20)})
```

Comment: I'll come back to this when I need some efficiency ^^

Answer (score 0):

Is this a solution for you?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A',1], ['A', 2], ['A', 3], ['B',1], ['B', 2],['C',1]], columns=['letter', 'number'])
df = df.groupby(['letter']).count()
df = df[df['number'] == df['number'].max()]
print(df)
```

I've groupped using `count()` and I got the `max()` value of the groupping

Answer (score 0):

```
data2 = df.groupby('Column').size()
data2[data2==data2.max()]
```